# How to provide class static method as a variable in Java?

Tags: java, selenium, static-methods

I am trying to wrap some code into a helper function to be able to reduce the amount of code. Below is a Selenium "Explicit wait" [example](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp):

```
WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("myDynamicElement")));
```

where `presenceOfElementLocated` and `id` are static methods of the `ExpectedConditions` and `By` classes respectively. What I would like to do, is to create a wrapper function that will look something like this:

```
public void waitForElement(Type condition1, Type by1, String identifier){
    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
   .until(ExpectedConditions.condition1(By.by1("myDynamicElement")));
}
```

However, obviously I can't just stick the "condition" and "by" directly like above. I know that in Python I would use `getattr` to return the value of the named attribute of `Class.name`.

How can I do that in Java?

**EDIT1**:
I would like to call this method in the following manner:

```
waitForElement(Type? condition, Type? by, String identifier)
```

where:

**condition** - one of the Selenium expected conditions
**by** is  - one of the Selenium by criteria
**identifier** (or locator) - web element to wait for.

**PS** `Type?` means that I am not sure what should be used here.

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? In Java 8 you may well be able to use method references and lambda expressions for this... It would also help if you'd provide an example of how you'd want to call this.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks a lot for your response. I am limited to Java 7 (or lower). I edited my question.

Comment: How would that work for a condition *other* than one which takes a single `By`? And if you're always using an identifier, wouldn't that always suggest `By.id`? Any reason you don't just want to pass in a `Predicate<WebDriver>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet Hopefully I understand your question. Identifier can be an `id` or a `class name` or  an `xpath` or else (perhaps I shouldn't have used the term "identifier" but rather an "element name"). Condition can only accept one `By`. The desired result for me is to use a single function(method) that will say: "Find element with name X, search for it By Y (class name for example) and wait for condition Z. Hopefully that makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I still just don't see how it's going to be much more useful than calling `waitForElement(presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("foo"))` (which is just using a static import for `presenceOfElementLocated`)

Comment: @JonSkeet If I call it like that (pass the whole block: `presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("foo"))`, how would I define the `waitForElement` function?

Comment: Just `<V> void waitForElement(Function<WebDriver, V> function)` should do, I think.